# Add TOC to PDF from XML/JSON/file?

Tags: pdf, xml

I currently have a PDF file without any ToC (for example, in Mac's Preview.app, I can't see the ToC in the sidebar).

But I have the TOC in XML format, where there is a title and a pagenumber where that section starts.

Is there any way I can add that TOC to my PDF file in a batch way?

Since I have the TOC in XML, I can basically parse it in any possible way, so if there were a command line to add an TOC item to a PDF, I could also do that.

Any ideas?

Comment: What is your PDF editor - Adobe Acrobat Pro? Windows or Linux or Mac?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is fairly simple to add bookmarks to a PDF using [Ghostscript](http://www.ghostscript.com/). The syntax is:

```
gs -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sOutputFile=out.pdf in.pdf pdfmarks
```

Where pdfmarks is a text file with contents like:

```
[/Title (Title Page) /Page 1 /OUT pdfmark
[/Title (Table of Contents) /Page 3 /OUT pdfmark
...
```

For nested levels, use the /Count attribute. For example:

```
[/Count 3 /Title (Chapter 1) /Page 1 /OUT pdfmark
[/Count -2 /Title (Section 1.1) /Page 2 /OUT pdfmark
[/Title (Section 1.1.1) /Page 3 /OUT pdfmark
[/Title (Section 1.1.2) /Page 4 /OUT pdfmark
[/Count -1 /Title (Section 1.2) /Page 5 /OUT pdfmark
[/Title (Section 1.2.1) /Page 6 /OUT pdfmark
[/Title (Section 1.3) /Page 7 /OUT pdfmark
```

The argument to /Count gives the number of immediately subordinate bookmarks. The sign of the argument sets the default display (negative for closed, positive for open).

If the bookmarks are not enough as a Table of Contents, there exist applications that
create a Table of Contents from bookmarks. I haven't used any such, but googling turned up
for example Mapsoft TOCBuilder which is a commercial Adobe Acrobat plug-in with trial.

Sources :
[PDF bookmarks with Ghostscript](http://blog.tremily.us/posts/PDF_bookmarks_with_Ghostscript/)
[How to generate bookmarks via ghostscript/pdfwrite/pdfmark](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1545064)

Comment: That works perfectly under Ubuntu! Thanks a lot :D Although it takes some time on 1200 pages (running Ubuntu in a VM). But still quite a lot easier than manually adding 130 bookmarks :-D

Comment: Nice! However, unicode characters, such as ’ (RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) display weirdly. Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

If you have just one file, here's a way you can do so using `pdfTeX`. It may be slightly convoluted but I know TeX (and don't know other tools) and it does the trick when I need it.

Here's a sample file which will copy the full contents of your `input.pdf` and adds a Table of Contents containing links to some page numbers.

```
% Set page size... this is A4, change to whatever you need
\pdfpagewidth=210mm
\pdfpageheight=297mm

% TeX always adds unwanted 1in left and top margins, this counteracts them.
\advance\hoffset by -1in
\advance\voffset by -1in

% This macro inserts a verbatim copy of one page from the source into the output.
\def\copypage#1{%
  \pdfximage page #1 {input.pdf}%
  \shipout\vbox{\pdfrefximage\pdflastximage}}

% Determine the total number of pages
\pdfximage{input.pdf}
\newcount\total
\total=\pdflastximagepages

% Define an iterator to copy the whole file
\def\copy{%
  \copypage{\the\pageno} % Copy the page given by current page number
  \advance\pageno by 1 % Increase page number by one
  \ifnum\pageno > \total
    \let\copy\relax % After the last page has been copied, stop
  \fi
  \copy} % This repeats the cycle until \copy is redefined to \relax at the very end

\copy % Run the cycle

% Here you add your outline
\pdfoutline goto page 1 {/Fit} count 2 {Chapter}
  \pdfoutline goto page 1 {/Fit} count -3 {Section}
    \pdfoutline goto page 1 {/Fit} {Item}
    \pdfoutline goto page 2 {/Fit} {Item}
    \pdfoutline goto page 3 {/Fit} {Item}
  \pdfoutline goto page 4 {/Fit} count 1 {Section}
    \pdfoutline goto page 4 {/Fit} count -2 {Subection}
      \pdfoutline goto page 1 {/Fit} {Item}
      \pdfoutline goto page 5 {/Fit} {Item}

\end
```

How to use the `\pdfoutline` command:

- Always supply a page number, even for section headers which might not be supposed to be used directly
- Replace "Chapter", "Item" etc. by your desired headers
- Supply a count for items which contain subitems (note that there's no "closing" command so TeX needs to know the count in advance)
- **EDIT** thanks to harrymc:
  Make the count negative if you want a item with subitems closed by default, leave it positive if you want it open

After preparing this input file, save it as, say, `output.tex`, and process it using `pdftex`. Voilà, this produces `output.pdf` with your shiny new ToC.

Comment: Can I add titles to the ToC with the pdfoutline command?

Comment: And I can't seem to figure out how to install and run PDFTex on either Windows and Mac? Help appreciated! :-)

Comment: @Elias Sorry, I forgot to mention. The titles to be displayed in your table are the last item between the `{...}` in each `\pdfoutline` line. I just chose "Chapter", "Item" etc. arbitrarily for my example to illustrate the meaning of the respective entries. Also, `pdftex` is a part of any TeX installation, for example, MikTeX for Windows. But if you have never worked with TeX I'm sure there would be better solutions for you.

Comment: I haven't used TeX before, so I had hoped there would be a more simple way. I have tried to do it with bookmarks in Acrobat Pro, but there are about 130 bookmarks, so it would take a lot of time.